# I am trying to show a url data using jsp jstl import

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications, liferay, jstl

I am trying to print data from url using below code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Tag Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <c:import var = "data" url = "www.google.com"/>
  <c:out value = "${data}"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

Always it is giving Timed out exception like below :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImp
```

Here I using Liferay 6.2 with tomcat 7.

Can I get any help please?

Thanks,
Naresh Kalalmadi.

Answer (score 2):

`www.google.com` is not a URL. `https://www.google.com` would be one.

However I'd try my experiments with a site that's available through http first, so that you first cover the basics and only later try to tackle certificate problems.

Related: As you tag Liferay, you're probably writing a portlet. Note that a portlet's JSP must not contain `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags as it generates only a small fragment that will later be embedded in a page.